# remove field name from object validation message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

I've got a simple active record validation on an object using this within a form:

```
  form.error_messages({:message => '', :header_message => ''})
```

This in turn outputs something like "FieldName My Custom message"

What i need to do is remove the field name from the error message but leave my custom message.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way to have complete control over the messages is to use a custom `validate` block in the model. e.g. to check that a field is not blank it would be like this:

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate do |model|
    model.errors.add_to_base("My Custom message") if user.field.blank?
  end
end
```

`add_to_base` is intended for adding messages that aren't related to a particular individual field (e.g. if a combination of multiple fields is illegal). This means that the CSS to highlight your invalid field won't get added. You can work arround this by also adding a nil message to the errors for your field e.g.

```
model.errors.add(:field, nil)
```

Alternatively, check out [custom-err-message](http://github.com/gumayunov/custom-err-msg) plugin - this plugin gives you the option to not have your custom validation error message prefixed with the attribute name.

**Update:**

`add_to_base` is deprecated since Rails 3. The following can be used instead:
`model_instance.errors.add(:base, "Msg")`
Ref: https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Errors/add_to_base

Comment: Cheers mikej, the custom-err-message plugin did just what i wanted

Comment: There is also a [gem](https://github.com/thethanghn/custom-err-msg) that worked for me in Rails 4.

Answer (score 12):

In rails 3.2.6, you can set this in a locale file (e.g., config/locales/en.yml):

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

Otherwise, the default format is "%{attribute} %{message}".

Comment: Still working in 5.2 if you want to globally remove attributes from error messages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use errors.add_to_base http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html#M001712

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object's [errors](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Errors.html) instance directly if you need full control over how the messages are presented.