# Exclude attribute name prepending in error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have a simple internationalization:

```
attributes:
  user:
    login: Login
errors:
  template:
    header: "Errors"
    body: ""
  models:
    user:
      attributes:
       login:
         taken: "The chosen {{attribute}} is already registered"
```

The resulting error message is as follows:

> Login The chosen Login is already registered

It seems, like Rails automatically prepends the error messsage with attribute name. This forces me to arrange messages in only one way - with attribute name as a first word.

I need the following error message:

> The chosen Login is already registered

How can I configure Rails to not prepend the error message with the attribute name?

Comment: I won't mark your question as a duplicate because it is slightly different due to the use of internationalisation, but see my previous answer to the following question to see if that helps you: [remove field name from object validation message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951333/remove-field-name-from-object-validation-message/2951461#2951461)

Comment: Actually, that's about to help me out, for a similar question that now won't have to be asked.

Answer (score 13):

You need to specify the error message format in order to remove the model name. I believe this is only possible as of Rails 3.2.6 and up. [There are more details](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) on the I18n chapter in Rails Guides.

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

The default is `%{attribute} %{message}`.

Comment: @MegaTux I believe so, yes. But I'm unsure.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no you cannot. I have been unable to figure it out.

Comment: @NickMcD.You can customize errors as granularly as possible, it is doable, working with the file isn't simple - but read the guide - it'll help