# How to set model validation message to not include attribute name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to show the user the error message "Arrangement has already been scheduled for this case" when a `case_id` is not unique on an `Arrangement`.

Here's my en.yml file:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        arrangement:
          attributes:
            case_id: 
              taken: "Arrangement has already been scheduled for this case"
```

But i keep getting the message "**Case** Arrangement has already been scheduled for this case".

How can i NOT show the field name in this error message?

Arrangement model

```
class Arrangement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :case
  validates_uniqueness_of :case_id, :allow_nil => true
...
```

EDIT:
The links suggested don't seem to work on a per model basis.

i.e. this does not seem to work. It still shows the message "**Case** Arrangement has already been scheduled for this case".

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        arrangement:
          format: "%{message}"
          attributes:
            case_id: 
              taken: "Arrangement has already been scheduled for this case"
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371423/exclude-attribute-name-prepending-in-error-message

Comment: See my edit. Doesn't seem to work for a specific model.